# al montar aplicación react en servidor no carga ningún componente

Tags: reactjs, arquitectura

tengo una aplicacióin en react la cual en servidor de desarrollo no tuvo problema y carga sin mayor esfuerzo, resulta que al pasar a qa, la aplicación dejó de ser renderizada y el archivo chunk.js.map arroja errores de sintaxis, será una configuración extra del servidor? como datos

1. en ambiente desarrollo las apis de node js tienen su propio dominio
   y    el front también tiene su propio dominio
2. servidor qa comparte
   dominio tanto para el front y back

Comment: Patricio copia y pega el error que te lanza la consola o de lo contrario no hay forma de saber que pasa.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.